# java.io.NotSerializableException: src.Item : How to get rid of having same repeated results to table?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I was trying to load my db's table to jsp table via servet search method.

My servelt serch query is like this.

```
PreparedStatement state = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


rs = state.executeQuery(search_sql);

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("arraylist", arList);

request.setAttribute("list", arList);
System.out.println("one");

response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

**Please consider this is not the whole code.**

This is the jsp page code.

```
    <tbody>
        <%
            List<Item> l = (ArrayList<Item>) session.getAttribute("arraylist");
            if (l != null) {
                for (Item it : l) {
        %>

        <tr>
            <td><%=it.getItem_id()%></td>
            <td><%=it.getName()%></td>
            <td><%=it.getUnit_price()%></td>
            <td><%=it.getQty()%></td>

        </tr>
        <%}
        %> 
    </tbody>
```

Also I made a class for Item table. This is it.

```
package src;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Item {
  private int item_id;

public int getItem_id() {
    return item_id;
}

public void setItem_id(int item_id) {
    this.item_id = item_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public BigDecimal getUnit_price() {
    return unit_price;
}

public void setUnit_price(BigDecimal unit_price) {
    this.unit_price = unit_price;
}

public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}
private String name;
private BigDecimal unit_price;
private int qty;
```

}

Now I'm having a

> WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute arraylist for session 9D5E8A2E292E5B711AA327FA51DE1D94 java.io.NotSerializableException: src.Item

in tomcat log. Also output of my jsp is only showing one result. Please help me. I'm in really complex situation. :( And deadline. Hope you can understand the question. Thank you.

**Edit 01:**

I get rid that error by implementing serializeble interface. Now I still have the same error. I only get result of the item details I saved last time.

[image]

Comment: implement `Serializable interface` to the `Item` class

Comment: @hrskrs then I'm having an exception saying org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Comment: try getting rid of `Getters`and `Setters`,make fields `public` and acces them directly

Comment: @hrskrs I fixed the error. It was a syntax error. Still I only having same output. which I saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is better that save your list in the request than in the session, is this way the list only last for the time of the request and avoid the problem of being *reutilized* from the session. And you will need to make sure that your code that fetch that data from database is executed every time that the page that lists it will be executed. And instead of use `request.sendRedirect` use `request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);` in this way the list inserted on request will be accessible in `jsp`.

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake if it answer your question, please mark as so. Thanks!